# Loop for displaying multidimensional PHP array WITHOUT echoing

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a `<ul>` tree to display a multidimensional PHP array, but all  of the examples I've seen involve echoing the output from within the for/foreach loop. I would like instead for the output of the recursive function to be stored in a variable without being echoed right away. Is this possible?

My code for the recursive display:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($tree) {       
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tree); $i++) {
        echo '<ul><li>'.$tree[$i]['name'];
        if(is_array($tree[$i]['children'])){                    
            $this->displayArrayRecursively($tree[$i]['children']);
        }
        echo '</li></ul>';
    }
}
```

But of course, that is echoing the output, which is not what I want. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use a variable to join all the output, like `$output .= '</li></ul>';` Dont forget to empty/clear it prior to each new loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate to a variable and then `return` it.  But you might consider renaming the function because it is no longer "display".  Maybe `formatArrayRecursively()`:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($tree) {  
    $output = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($tree); $i++) {
        $output .= '<ul><li>'.$tree[$i]['name'];

        if(is_array($tree[$i]['children'])){                    
            $output .= $this->displayArrayRecursively($tree[$i]['children']);
        }
        $output .= '</li></ul>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
$var = $this->displayArrayRecursively($something);
```

As an aside, for arrays a `foreach` is simpler:

```
foreach($tree as $val) {
    $output .= '<ul><li>'.$val['name'];

    if(is_array($val['children'])){                    
        $output .= $this->displayArrayRecursively($val['children']);
    }
    $output .= '</li></ul>';
}
```

Comment: Perfect, nailed it! Thanks!

Comment: I tried doing it your way before posting, but what I had forgotten was to set the output to blank at the top of the function, causing tons of repetition. Thanks for the missing piece!

Answer (score 1):

```
function displayArrayRecursively($tree) {
$output = '';       
for($i = 0; $i < count($tree); $i++) {
    $output .= '<ul><li>'.$tree[$i]['name'];
    if(is_array($tree[$i]['children'])){                    
        $output .= $this->displayArrayRecursively($tree[$i]['children']);
    }
    $output .= '</li></ul>';
}
return $output;
}
```